# How to attach textures to fbx file? (model import by using addon CC)

Tags: texturing, export, import, unity, .fbx

I imported the model from character creator using the CC/iC Pipeline addon (otherwise the textures were displayed incorrectly), now I need to export this model to the Unity, but the textures are not attached, either without them, or a separate folder with textures is created.
How to embed them in the FBX file itself?
Otherwise, the problem is when unpacking and assigning textures to materials...

Answer (score 0):

In the export pop-up, choose *Path Mode > Copy* and enable the *Embed Textures* option:

[image]

Comment: when it works with normal export, but if I previously imported the model using the addon CC, then it does not work, the file is without textures inside .... this is the problem...

Comment: Oh ok sorry I hope someone will understand